# Raspbian Jessie (RPI3) boot options not launching Desktop

Tags: python, linux, matlab, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm trying to connect raspberry pi with MatLab. I use the toolbox within matlab to configure raspberry pi. It automatically connects through network however it also gives you OS within that setup procedure, you can't connect to raspberry pi without it. Although the system it gives is technically Raspbian Jessie it comes with limited package.

When it launches and I input `dir` into console it only shows files such as: `satkin_ws` `install ros_indigo.sh` `install_ros_package.sh` and `ros_catkin_ws`. No other folders or files are pre-loaded onto the system. I tried to install some packages for `display manager` such as `gdm3` and `lightdm` but I still have a problem with loading desktop environment. Can someone give me suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Alright after doing some research I found that the system installed by Matlab is Raspbian Jessie Lite which does not come with GUI/Desktop environment by default but you can install it you want. Here is the link to get you going:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=133691